# Environment variable in ocelot config file

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ocelot

I have multiple microservices which are accessible by clients through `Ocelot` gateway. Inside configuration file there are properties to specify downstream host and port. This have to be done for EACH route.

The problem is that if the service's hostname or port changes, I will have to modify every single route associated with this particular service.

So, the question is, Is it possible to introduce ENV variable inside `ocelot.json` configuration file? In that case I will have to modify only one ENV variable and all associated routes will be affected.

Here is my current configuration file (I'm using `docker-compose` so service names are used as hosts):

```
"Routes": [
    {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/signIn",
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/signIn",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "identity-api",
          "Port": 80
        }
      ],
      "SwaggerKey": "Identity"
    },
    {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/validate",
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/validate",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "identity-api",
          "Port": 80
        }
      ],
      "SwaggerKey": "Identity"
    },
```

What I want:

```
"Routes": [
    {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/signIn",
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/signIn",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": {SERVICE_HOST},
          "Port": {SERVICE_PORT}
        }
      ],
      "SwaggerKey": "Identity"
    },
    {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/validate",
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/validate",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": {SERVICE_HOST},
          "Port": {SERVICE_PORT}
        }
      ],
      "SwaggerKey": "Identity"
    },
```

Comment: This feature is missing in Ocelot, but will be very useful. I didn't try it yet but I think it can be possible to workaroud it with `PostConfigure` extension method on `IConfiguration`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to implement this missing functionality with `PostConfigure` extension method. In my case I prefer to put placeholders configuration into `Ocelot.json` but you can change the code to look in `IConfiguration` rather using `GlobalHosts`

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Configuration.File;

public static class FileConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection ConfigureDownstreamHostAndPortsPlaceholders(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.PostConfigure<FileConfiguration>(fileConfiguration =>
        {
            var globalHosts = configuration
                .GetSection($"{nameof(FileConfiguration.GlobalConfiguration)}:Hosts")
                .Get<GlobalHosts>();

            foreach (var route in fileConfiguration.Routes)
            {
                ConfigureRote(route, globalHosts);
            }
        });

        return services;
    }

    private static void ConfigureRote(FileRoute route, GlobalHosts globalHosts)
    {
        foreach (var hostAndPort in route.DownstreamHostAndPorts)
        {
            var host = hostAndPort.Host;
            if (host.StartsWith("{") && host.EndsWith("}"))
            {
                var placeHolder = host.TrimStart('{').TrimEnd('}');
                if (globalHosts.TryGetValue(placeHolder, out var uri))
                {
                    route.DownstreamScheme = uri.Scheme;
                    hostAndPort.Host = uri.Host;
                    hostAndPort.Port = uri.Port;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `GlobalHosts` class:

```cs
public class GlobalHosts : Dictionary<string, Uri> { }
```

The usage:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddOcelot();
    services.ConfigureDownstreamHostAndPortsPlaceholders(Configuration);
}
```

The `Ocelot.json`

```json
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/my-resource",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST" ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/my/resource",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "{MyService}"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:5000",
    "Hosts": {
      "MyService": "http://localhost:3999"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I had multiple ocelot files and put the GlobalConfiguration/hosts section in my appsettings.json and then it worked.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry sir, but i didnt get it. You mean ocelot.json globalconfiguration setting can be inside appsettings.json

Comment: @Flamealchemist correct. `ocelot.json` is just a convenient file to place routing related configuration, but since it's added to the .NET configuration framework, its content is merged with `appsettings.json` behind the scenes. So you can place it wherever you want.

Comment: Thanks alot i will check it. one more doubt can we do the placeholders in baseurl too. is it possible and if it is how can we achieve it. it will very helpful if you can help me sir.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding the global configuration in appsettings.json and in my startup i tried to read the appsettings.json first and than override it.

example:

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
    Configuration = configuration;
    Environment = environment; 
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(); 
    var configJson = File.ReadAllText($"appsettings.{Environment.EnvironmentName}.json");
    var config = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(configJson);
    config["GlobalConfiguration:BaseUrl"] = config["GlobalConfiguration:BaseUrl"].ToString().Replace("{{tenant}}", Environment.IsDevelopment() ? "local" : "{gatewayhost}");
            
    var updatedConfigJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(config, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
            
    File.WriteAllText($"appsettings.{Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", updatedConfigJson);
            
    builder.SetBasePath(environment.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true)
    .AddJsonFile($"ocelot.{Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();  

    Configuration = builder.Build();

    }
```

### appsettings.json

```
{
"GlobalConfiguration:BaseUrl": "https://{{gatewayhost}}.subdomain.com"
}
```

by using this method we can override the baseurl as per our requirement.
and above postconfigure we can use for the host and port changes to downstream. as above one works well.

Answer (score -1):

I used the first answer, but it didn't work for me. I made my own implementation.

```cs
using Ocelot.Infrastructure.Extensions;

namespace APIGateway;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Configuration.File;

public static class OcelotFileConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static void ConfigureDownstreamHostAndPortsPlaceholders(
        this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.PostConfigure<FileConfiguration>(fileConfiguration =>
        {
            ConfigureGlobal(fileConfiguration.GlobalConfiguration);
            ConfigureRoutes(fileConfiguration.Routes);
        });
    }

    private static void ConfigureGlobal(FileGlobalConfiguration configuration)
    {
        configuration.BaseUrl = CheckEnvironmentVariable("APPLICATION_BASE_URL");
    }

    private static string CheckEnvironmentVariable(string name)
    {
        var value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name);
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"{name} variable is not set");
        }
        
        return value;
    }

    private static void ConfigureRoutes(List<FileRoute> routes)
    {
        foreach (var route in routes)
        {
            ConfigureRote(route);
        }
    }
    
    private static void ConfigureRote(FileRoute route)
    {
        foreach (var hostAndPort in route.DownstreamHostAndPorts)
        {
            var host = hostAndPort.Host;
            if (host != null && host.StartsWith("${") && host.EndsWith("}"))
            {
                var environmentVariableName = host.TrimStart("${").TrimEnd('}');
                var environmentVariable = CheckEnvironmentVariable(environmentVariableName);

                var url = new Uri(environmentVariable);
                hostAndPort.Host = url.Host;
                hostAndPort.Port = url.Port;
                if (route.DownstreamScheme != "ws")
                {
                    route.DownstreamScheme = url.Scheme;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `Ocelot.json`:

```json
"Routes": [
    {
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
        "Post", "Get"
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/posts",
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/posts",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "${BLOG_API_URL}"
        }
      ],
      "RouteIsCaseSensitive": true
    },
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "${APPLICATION_BASE_URL}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**